# QueryRecord vs. PartitionRecord for better performance?

Tags: java, performance, etl, apache-nifi

In a NiFi dataflow if I want to split a single flowfile into two sets based on the value of a particular field, is it faster, in terms of performance, to use QueryRecord or PartitionRecord in the following manners?

**QueryRecord:**

`SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE WEIGHT < 1000;`

**PartitionRecord**

1. In `UpdateRecord` in *RecordPath* mode populate a new "string" field `greater_or_less` with the value of `/weight`
2. In `UpdateRecord` in *Literal Value* mode update `greater_or_less` to `${field.value:toNumber():lt(1000)}`
3. In `PartitionRecord` partition the flowfile on `greater_or_less`

In the PartitionRecord method, I will have two schemas, with one being the original data format, and the other having the `greater_or_less` field in addition to the original data format. We'll begin step 1 in the original schema,  output from step 1 in the new schema, and then output step 3 in the original schema. The output of step 3 should be two flowfiles, one being equivalent to the output of the QueryRecord method.

In summation, although `QueryRecord` is a bit simpler to implement, I don't have any knowledge of the back-end machinations of NiFi, or how the overheads of these processors compare, so I am not sure which method is optimal. My instincts tell me that `QueryRecord` is expensive, but I am not sure how it compares to the type-switching and record-reading-and-writing of the `PartitionRecord` method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which is faster off the top of my head, but both run on Apache Calcite under the covers which is very quick.
Have you considered using GenerateFlowfile to produce test data and try it out?

I would expect that PartitionRecord would be best, but use a [filter with a predicate](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#predicates) instead of generating a new field in your schema with UpdateRecord.

Answer (score 0):

Both use a Record Reader and Writer for record level processing. So there is no difference on convert Record Abstract Processor in both's implmentation.

The differnce is PartitionRecord access type is native and faster to record level processing on the other hand QueryRecord has an extra overhead of running SQL for which it has to structure its records and metadata according to Calcite specififcations which is an overhead.

Some 5 minute stats I was able to process 47GB of data with a task time of 1:18:00 on QueryRecord while 0:47:00 on PartitionRecord with same number of threads.